# DataTable does not support schema inference

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datatable

I have many datatable in my application and some of them needs to be imported from xmls. Every readxml function works well except for one.

Here is the some of the xml content;

```
 <dtSysStat>
    <ST>2017-11-28T21:14:58+03:00</ST>
    <INST_ID>1</INST_ID>
    <RM>1.34</RM>
    <WM>0.04</WM>
    <RR>86</RR>
    <WR>2</WR>
    <TR>0</TR>
  </dtSysStat>
```

Here is the datatable structure;

```
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("ST", typeof(DateTime));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("INST_ID", typeof(int));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("RM", typeof(double));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("WM", typeof(double));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("RR", typeof(double));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("WR", typeof(double));
dtSysStatTemp.Columns.Add("TR", typeof(double));
```

Here is the reading section;

```
dtSysStatTemp.TableName = "dtSysStat";
dtSysStatTemp.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + pathnameicustom);
```

I also write this xml from the dtsysstat datatable structure. so i am sure that schema structure is same.

I don't why i getting 'DataTable does not support schema inference' error. Because all of the other datatable with readxml work perfectly.

I want to do this without using Dataset

Comment: Why use a DataTable in the first place? Why not strongly typed objects?

Comment: There is a slight difference between DataSet WriteXml and DataTable WriteXml.  The DataSet works all the time.  The DataTable only works when the DataTable has a name.  Do not ask me why.  When reading a DataSet the first level tag is the DataSet name.  Second Level tags are the DataTable names.  Third Level tags are the column names.  Fourth Level tags are the row data.  When you have more than four layers the Net Library breaks the data into many datatables that are useless.  When you try to read same file as a DataTable it becomes impossible because you can't create multiple datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below using a dataset.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("testfile.xml");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["dtSysStat"];
return dt.Rows[0]["ST"].ToString();
```

Alt solution (adding ReadXmlSchema):

```
dtSysStatTemp.TableName = "dtSysStat";
dtSysStatTemp.ReadXmlSchema(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + pathnameicustom);
dtSysStatTemp.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + pathnameicustom);
```

Comment: I dont want to use dataset.

Comment: People are putting effort and time to help you, i think "I dont want to use dataset" is not respectable comment, please explain why.

Comment: If you use ReadXmlSchema just before ReadXml, does that make a difference? I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score -1):

1. make sure you dont have white space in you tags for example:
   **wrong**: `< ST > < /ST>` **correct**:  `<ST> </ST>`.
2. use `DataSet` and not `DataTable` - DataTable does not support schema
   inference from Xml.

I have tested it and it works as expected:

```
private void XmlToDataset() 
{
    DataSet dsysStatTemp = new DataSet();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string xmlString = @"<dtSysStat>
     <ST> 2017 - 11 - 28T21: 14:58 + 03:00 </ST>
     <INST_ID> 1 </INST_ID>
     <RM> 1.34 </RM>
     <WM> 0.04 </WM>
     <RR> 86 </RR>
     <WR> 2 </WR>
     <TR> 0 </TR>
     </dtSysStat>";

    doc.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));

    XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(doc.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Element, null);
    dsysStatTemp.ReadXml(xtr);
    MessageBox.Show(dsysStatTemp.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ST"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: however i can use all of the other datatablest without using dataset.

Comment: i did not understand your comment. also,i wish people would explain why they down vote.